# Is there a more concise way to print this out by using the dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a more concise way to print this out?

```
countries = {
    'france': ['paris', 'bordeaux', 'marseille'],
    }

for country, cities in countries.items():
    print(f"These are some of the cities of {country.title()}:", end = ' ')
    for city in cities:
        if city != cities[-1]:
            print(city.title(), end = ', ')
        else:
            print(f"{city.title()}.")
```

Expected output:

```
These are some of the cities of France: Paris, Bordeaux, Marseille.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put any python expression into an f-string. The `str.join` method will add separator between list items. And python string literals within parenthesis such as in a function call can be written on multiple lines. So, your code can change to

```
countries = {
    'france': ['paris', 'bordeaux', 'marseille'],
    }

for country, cities in countries.items():
    print(f"These are some of the cities of {country.title()}: "
            f"{', '.join(city.title() for city in cities)}")
```

Comment: Why 2 fs are used?

Comment: Those are both f-strings and each needs a "f" for python to know that. When the program is compiled, python concatenates adjacent strings. So for instance, `"foo" "bar"` becomes `"foobar"`. In this case, python resolves the two f-strings and then concatenates them. I only did it so that the example would fit on the page. A single, longer f-string works just as welll.... except that it violates python's PEP8 style guide.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the second loop (`cities`) with this single line:

```
print(", ".join(map(str.title, cities)) + ".")
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this one-liner:

```py
print(next(f'These are some of the cities of {k.title()}: {", ".join(map(str.title, v))}.' for k,v in countries.items()))
```

result

```
These are some of the cities of France: Paris, Bordeaux, Marseille.
```